# Delete user from databse using InertiaJs & Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-8, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I'm having a problem deleting a record from the database. I'm using InertiaJS & Laravel.

**Component Code**
The following is the link/button code:

```
<Link class="trash" @click="submit(result.ChildID)">
                    Move to Trash
                </Link>
```

**Note :**  ChildID is the id of a child record in the database.

**Now:** When a user clicks this link, a method will be called, which is given below.

```
   methods: {
        submit: function (ChildID) {
            alert(ChildID)
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this child?")) {
                this.$inertia.delete('destroy/ChildID');
             }
        },
    },
```

**Route Code**

```
Route::delete('destroy/{childID}',[childrenController::class,'destroy']);
```

**Controller Code**

```
  public function destroy(children $childID){
     
         $childID->delete();
         return redirect()->route('View_Child_Profile');
    }
```

Now when I'm **hitting** the delete button, I'm getting the following **error**:

[image]

Comment: What is your table structure? That error indicates you don't have an if column on the childrens table

Comment: @LLai I have the following columns in my table

ChildID,
child_name, 
child_address, 
child_aim, 
user_id, 
created_at, 
updated_at,

Comment: run `php artisan route:list` and check the parameter name.

Comment: @itachi I got the following result after executing the above query :


->  DELETE    destroy/{childID} .................................................. children › childrenController@destroy

Comment: in your model, add `protected $primaryKey = 'ChildID';` and run again.

Comment: @itachi after adding the above line to the model, when I executed the code I got an error 
"404 | NOT FOUND"

Comment: post your table schema. There is something missing in the schema that you wrote.

Comment: Here is the schema of table children: 



  Schema::create('childrens', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('ChildID'); 
            $table->string('child_name');
            $table->string('child_address');
            $table->string('child_aim');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Answer (score 2):

try this. I think you are doing mistake "this.$inertia.delete('destroy/ChildID');"

```
   methods: {
    submit: function (ChildID) {
        alert(ChildID)
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this child?")) {
            this.$inertia.delete(`destroy/${ChildID}`);
            // or
            this.$inertia.delete('destroy/'+ChildID);
         }
      },
   },
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I handle delete process .

Front Vue + Inertia:

```
import { Link } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
```

In Template :

```
<Link method="delete" :href="route('admin.insta_feeds.destroy',id)">Delete</Link>
```

Back End Laravel:

Route :

```
Route::resource('insta_feeds', InstaFeedsController::class);
```

Controller Function :

```
    public function destroy(InstaFeed $insta_feed)
{
  if(isset($insta_feed->image_path)){
    Storage::delete($insta_feed->image_path);
  }
    $insta_feed->delete();
    return Redirect::route('admin.insta_feeds.index');
}
```